# "DHCP...PXE E-53 No boot Filename received" timeout takes way too long

Tags: networking, dhcp, tftp

I set up a PXE-boot network under Linux Debian.
I used following components for this:

pxelinux, dhcp3, tftp-hpa

For every client in my network, i configured a host declaration in /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf.

In this host declaration they'll get:    static IP, gateway, bootfilename "pxelinux.0", dns-server

This configuration works totally. **But** when I want the client to boot the boot filename I am configuring this clients' host declaration with the filename option. When I don't want this client to boot the filename, then I'll delete this line from its' host declaration. Everytime one line was edited in the /etc/dhcp3/dhcp.conf I am restarting the dhcp-server to reparse the configuration.

This works too. But When the client boots **without** the filename option it struggles searching for a bootfilename (output for about 30 seconds: "DHCP......." )and exits with  PXE E-53: No boot filename received.

This is what I completely don't understand. When this client has no filename option bound to its' host declaration, why should it take so long to search for a boot filename? Is there a way to tell this client to NOT search for this boot filename? or is there eventually a way to set the timeout for getting a boot filename to less than 5 seconds? Waiting more than 1 minute for nothing to boot one host is an absolute time waste in my environment, thats why I am asking.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the way a client boots is set on its bios set-up
if the client is meant to boot from the net it will always wait for an NBP (Network Boot Loader) no matter if you provide it or not on the DHCP transaction.

if you want the client not to perform a PXE boot the just change the BIOS setting telling i.e. it should boot from the client HDD